# Passing values to parameters in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Suppose I have a variable in the RequestParameter as StudentList list where StudentList is a class as follows:

```
class StudentList
{
 List<Students> stud=new ArrayList<Students>();
}
```

and Students is a class having fields firstName,lastName etc.How to pass values to the list variable in Jmeter as a request parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to the list variable in Jmeter via CSV Data Set Config. Where you have to create first .CSV file with values and set the parameters in the HTTP request. Below are shared steps with screenshots of results.

1. Create an HTTP request under the Thread group and change the name to **"Student"**
2. Select CSV Data Set Config from Config Element under the same Thread Group
3. Create .CSV file with values related firstname and lastname and set the loop count in the Thread Group as 3 as there are 3 records available in CSV file

   [CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6ZYE.png)
4. Set Path in CSV Data Set Config under Filename and Set the variable name as
   "firstname,lastname"
   [CSV Dat Set Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vlXw.png)
5. Set the parameter in value with the $ sign as per the attached screenshot.

   [Request Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8QLu.png)
6. Select View Result Tree from Listener under the same Thread Group
7. Save the Test plan and Run or Start.
8. Under the view result tree, when clicking on each request you will find firstname and last name under each request parameter.

   [Student 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwiLA.png)

   [Student 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUZK9.png)

   [Student 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woPyl.png)